# How to force download a .rtf file in PHP?

Tags: php, file, download, content-type, rtf

So the code I have used for a button to download a wordpad .rtf file is the following:

My php script:

```
 <?php 

    if(isset($_POST['file_name'])){
    $file = $_POST['file_name'];
    header('Content-type: application/rtf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
    readfile('uploads/'.$file);
    exit();
    }
```

and the div associated:

```
<div class ="buttonhol">
    <h2> <center> HOLIDAY REQUEST FORM </center> </h2>
    <form action="rota.php" method="post" name="downloadform">
  <input name="file_name" value="HolidayRequestForm.rtf" type="hidden">
  <input type="submit" value="Download Holiday Request Form">
    </div>
```

--
I have used the exact same code for an excel file in the same folder 'Uploads' however the content-type matches as appropriate. When I click the 'Download Holiday Request Form' button.. the document that gets downloaded is titled correctly however the file just contains all the code written in that particular php class.

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: are you actully creating the file?

Comment: @Dagon The file i'm trying to make downloadable is already pre-written, my problem is that when i download the file, the file contains my PHP code from the class where code is written in!

Comment: if you just visit the url of `..uploads/HolidayRequestForm.rtf` do you get the correct file

Comment: @Dagon can you please be a bit more specific? I'm unsure as to what you're asking.. the HolidayRequestForm.rtf is located inside the 'Uploads' folder

Comment: @Dagon and when i open the file from the 'Uploads' folder, it displays the content I want within the file

Comment: you could really just substitute this thing with `<a href="/uploads/HolidayRequestForm.rtf">`

Comment: @Dagon not sure why but it didn't work. Tbh, I would like to know why the format I followed (exactly the same) for an excel file worked but wordpad didn't..

Comment: can you provide the url?

Comment: @Dagon Although it feels unprofessional as I wanted to implement a button, I have decided to just make a link to the document and border the link in css.. thank you very much for the time you took to respond to my question and responses, all the best Dagon.